# Using query to populate columns from another tab based upon whether dates sit between two dates

Tags: excel, date, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to populate a sheet with data in columns from another sheet (Weekly). So far I'm able to do so successfully based upon the start of a month. I'd also like to be able to only select data where it exists before an end date (which would be the end of the month, in this case)

Current Formula:

```
=query(Weekly!$B$7:$K$99,"select E, B, C, I, J, D, H, G where I >= date '"&text(G9,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)
```

I think the select statement should be something like this, but I can't get it to work:

```
"select E, B, C, I, J, D, H, G where I >= date '"&text(G7,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and where I <= date '"&text(EOMONTH(G7),1)&"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(Weekly!B7:K99, 
 "select E,B,C,I,J,D,H,G 
  where I >= date '"&TEXT(G7,             "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and I <= date '"&TEXT(EOMONTH(G7, 1), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```